# Servers showing as unavailable through invites Discordjs v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
guild.invites.fetch().then((invites) => {
  if (!invites.size) return message.channel.send('No invites found');
  let allInvites = invites.forEach(async(e) => {
    var invGuild = await client.guilds.fetch(e.guild)
    if(!invGuild.available) {console.log("Server unavailable?"); return;}
    console.log('Premade Invite Code: https://discord.gg/' + e.code + " | Server: " + invGuild.name + " | Member Count: " + invGuild.memberCount)
    i++
  })
}).then( async() => {
  if(i==0) {
    var channel = await client.channels.fetch(channelid)
    var invite = await channel.createInvite()
    console.log('No invites found, new invite: ' + invite.code)
  }
})
```

This code takes the invites of a guild, checks the size to see if there is any, then loops through them all. The issue I am having is that `var invGuild = await client.guilds.fetch(e.guild)` and fetching from the client by `invGuild.id` shows as unavailable but the invite code works and e.guild returns the guild id when fetching the guilds from `client`.

TL;DR: Guild from e.guild (e being the invite) returning as unavailable.

I'm sure I'm just missing something from a syntax update, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
      let i = 0;

  client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
    guild.invites.fetch().then((invites) => {
      if (!invites.size) return console.log('No invites found.');
      invites.forEach(async(e) => {
        var invGuild = await client.guilds.fetch(e.guild.id);
        if(!invGuild.available) {console.log("Server unavailable?"); return;}
        console.log('Premade Invite Code: https://discord.gg/' + e.code + " | Server: " + invGuild.name + " | Member Count: " + invGuild.memberCount)
        i++
      })
    }).then( async() => {
      if(i==0) {
        const channel = await client.channels.fetch(guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText).first().id);
        const invite = await channel.createInvite({ maxAge: 0 }).catch(err => console.log(err.rawError.message)) // We catch a possible APIError if the bot doesn't have permission to  create invites.
        console.log('No invites found, new invite: ' + invite.code)
      }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err.rawError.message))

  })
```

I corrected it to fit your needs, here is a basic overview of this snippet:

We start by looping through the `client.guilds` cahce a getting the invites for each guild in the cache.

We then then check if there are any invites for the server, if there are none, we return and continue on to the next then.

If there are any invites available, we loop through them all and check if the guild they lead to is available, if it is, we log the invite's details.

In the next .then statement, we get the first text channel from the guild by filtering the cache and returning the first result, we then create a new invite that doesn't expire and then log it out.

If you have any questions please comment them below, if this helped please make sure to mark this as the solution.

Comment: Yes, I already have channelid. It still doesn't work, maybe it's because how I'm executing it? You're doing .on('message') but I'm doing it .on('ready').

Comment: Okay, I edited it to fit your needs, please review it and decide if it is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Im confused, I have no issue with creating the invites. The issue is getting the name and member count

`console.log('Premade Invite Code: https://discord.gg/' + e.code + " | Server: " + invGuild.name + " | Member Count: " + invGuild.memberCount)`

.memberCount and .name return as undefined

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I just said that when its logging in console, invGuild.name and invGuild.memberCount returns undefined

Comment: Shoot, just so you know, I got rid of the unavailable check thing just so you know